# Hiding submit button until file is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide the submit button until a file is chosen.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="imageURL[]" id="imageURL" />

     <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the submit button initially and on change of the input type file event show the submit button.

something like this -

```
$("#imageURL").on("change", function(){
    $("#submit").show();  
})
```

I have prepared [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linux_nerd/3Nt4E/) using jquery.

Hope this will help.

Comment: It worked, But if the user clicked cancel the submit button is appearing

Comment: It will still show the submit button, if the user doesn't select any file.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is better:

```
$('[type=submit]').hide();

setInterval(function(){
    if($('#imageURL').val()!=""){
     $('[type=submit]').show();
    }else{
        $('[type=submit]').hide();
    }
},1000);
```

Demo:<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/s24ZW/14/</kbd>